# Hibernate Search : How to update an index by two Spring(JVM) processes?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

My Application has two components running in two different JVM processes.

1) Spring Boot RestAPI

2) Spring Boot batch process (process jobs submitted by API)

I use "Hibernate Search" with Spring and both of these components need to update the search-index.

However it seems like a lock is aquired by the JVM process which starts first and when the other component trying to update the index , it throws following exception.

How can I make both is these JVM processes update the index without having this Lock issue ?

```
2017-05-22 02:33:56.795 ERROR 14701 --- [del.FeatureMeta] o.h.s.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler     : HSEARCH000058: Exception occurred org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: /home/bisuser/cdna-meta-index/default/com.company.dsd.cdna.repository.model.FeatureMeta/write.lock
Primary Failure:
    Entity com.company.dsd.cdna.repository.model.FeatureMeta  Id 169  Work Type  org.hibernate.search.backend.UpdateLuceneWork


org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by another program: /home/bisuser/cdna-meta-index/default/com.company.dsd.cdna.repository.model.FeatureMeta/write.lock
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:118) ~[lucene-core-5.5.4.jar!/:5.5.4 31012120ebbd93744753eb37f1dbc5e654628291 - jpountz - 2017-02-08 19:08:03]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41) ~[lucene-core-5.5.4.jar!/:5.5.4 31012120ebbd93744753eb37f1dbc5e654628291 - jpountz - 2017-02-08 19:08:03]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45) ~[lucene-core-5.5.4.jar!/:5.5.4 31012120ebbd93744753eb37f1dbc5e654628291 - jpountz - 2017-02-08 19:08:03]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:776) ~[lucene-core-5.5.4.jar!/:5.5.4 31012120ebbd93744753eb37f1dbc5e654628291 - jpountz - 2017-02-08 19:08:03]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.createNewIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:126) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:92) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriter(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:117) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriterDelegate(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:203) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.applyUpdates(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:81) [hibernate-search-engine-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.run(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:46) [hibernate-search-engine-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.applyChangesets(SyncWorkProcessor.java:165) [hibernate-search-engine-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.run(SyncWorkProcessor.java:151) [hibernate-search-engine-5.6.1.Final.jar!/:5.6.1.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]
```

Comment: See if [my this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043025/java-lucene-set-lock-timeout-for-indexwriter-in-java/44065003#44065003) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclusive locks are necessary in order for Lucene to offer decent performance. You could disable it, but there is a cost.

The reason is there will still be a locking mechanism, though the locks will be used only for small periods of time. This means that indexes won't be written to in parallel, and that the other JVM process may wait trying to acquire locks (potentially bad performance). Worse, these attempts at acquiring locks may fail: they may time out. Given that the lock queue isn't fair (the last JVM process to ask for the lock may be the first to get it), and that the timeout handling is rather crude (one try, then another something like 2s later, then timeout) there's a high risk of failure here.

So if you're sure that there won't be any strong contention over the locks (for example mass indexing jobs only run during the night, or on week-ends), disabling exclusive locking may be an option; otherwise, you're likely to end up with dramatic lags and/or failures due to lock timeouts.
See `hibernate.search.[default|<indexname>].exclusive_index_use`
 in [the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#table-performance-parameters).

Alternatively:

- you could ponder whether you really need those two things (REST API and batch processing) to occur in different JVMs (but I guess you did)
- you could have a look at the [JGroups](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_jgroups)/[JMS](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-architecture-jms) alternative architectures for Hibernate Search. However, those are admittedly harder to configure, and you should be aware that [dynamic sharding won't work well](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2676).
- If you need the JVMs to run on separate servers, and if horizontal scaling (adding more application servers) is something that matters in your specific case, you could have a look at [the experimental Elasticsearch integration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-integration).